# How to create a window group in java?

Tags: java, jinternalframe

i want to create a jframe that contains dynamic windows , like the windows group in Netbeans (palette, properties window, projects window ... ), anyone have an idea how to do it in java ?
thanks .

Comment: I don't have any idea except the jinternalframe, but i can"t find an example or a tutorial that helps !

Comment: Wel, this is not a tutorial site. You have to show your efforts (i.e.: your code) and explain where you're stuck at. Then possibly get some help

Comment: I know x) , but because i can't find documentation, and i'm a beginner , i was asking for help to start with , but thx anyway : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments - JInternalFrame is the typical way to do this in Swing.  The Oracle tutorial on JInternalFrames is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).